# How to enable flash on Chromium

Tags: chrome, adobe-flash

How do you get Adobe's flash video to play on Chromium? Is it [this painful](https://superuser.com/q/17682/), or is there somewhere an extension?

**NOTE**: On Debian, I install **flashplugin-nonfree** for Mozilla-based browsers. Is there an equivalent package for Chrome?

**UPDATE**: I needed to re-install **flashplugin-nonfree** for this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chromium can also use the Mozilla plugins. Just install it and it should work. What distro are you using?

Comment: I use Debian GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

For users browsing this forum after 2013, there's also a Debian **pepperflashplugin-nonfree** package, which is simply a wrapper to download Google's official Chrome browser and extract the Pepper Flash plugin that's bundled with newer versions of Chrome.

This can also be done by manually downloading and extracting (or installing) Google Chrome. Under a default installation, the bundled Flash plugin can be found at `/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/`.

Comment: There HAS to be an easier way to install that plugin.

Answer (score -1):

This comment is added on May 18, 2016.  There are news that Google will end support for flash at the end of year 2016.  They are also removing the support for NPAPI plugins.  If you are using flash to view video, most browser now support html5 based video player.

References.

[Chrome support for NPAPI plugins no longer available](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/TYbj21PkcAQ)

[Google to phases out support of Flash](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-36301904)

Comment: This is not exactly an answer to the question being asked but considering the question is 5+ years old, it is a moot point right now.

Comment: Not moot, came here in 2018 looking to see how to make flash work in linux on a fresh install of Mint